# Wait for page loading in xcuitest

Tags: ios, xcuitest

How can I wait for page to load completely (All UI elements becomes visible to user) and i want a dynamic approach as every page is different and i don't have a specific element(button/static text) to use for wait.

I tried `app.waitForExistence(timeout: 10)` which passes even before UI element becomes visible.

Comment: Unfortunately, you do need an element to key off of. Can you provide the view hierarchy?

Comment: I'm surprised what you tried above didn't throw an error; waitForExistence is a function of XCUIElement, which app should not be. Regardless, if app is a valid type the code is checking that your app exists and proceeding immediately. Obviously, the app exists.

Comment: It’s a ebook application and I’m taking screenshots of ebook pages for some testing but I don’t know how to wait for page loading after swipe left to next page, and as it a ebook every page have different text hence I can’t identify a particular element

Comment: Do you have page numbers? Is there any animation when pages are swiped? Could you possibly embed a hidden element containing page numbers?

Comment: My general rule of thumb is that if a framework cannot do what I’m seeking, it’s not the right tool for the job. Not always the case, as I do end up building my own functionality from time to time, but perhaps there is another tool that can do this for you? Are you manually validating these screenshots? If so, and expedience of your run isn’t important, a long sleep() may be what you need.

Comment: Long sleep would make my script a lot slower and for validating i have written script in java.

Comment: And this xcui script i am updating it thats why i cannot use different framework.

Comment: It sounds like you’re doing content validation? I’d argue that’s not a great use of UI testing, although “page turning” definitely is. I’d be asking development to provide me something to validate that on.